# При вводе чисел не меняется значение выражения

Tags: c++

```
double b = 2.5, m = 3, a = 1.4e-3, j, y, z; 
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << "j = ";
    cin >> j;
    y = (m * j) / tan(a) - exp(10 * m);
    z = 2 * y * b + sqrt(a + b);
    cout << "y = " << y << "\n";
    cout << "z = " << z << "\n";
}
```

Когда ввожу разные значения с клавиатуры, значения не меняются. Как испраить данную ошибку?

Comment: значения чего не меняется?   У вас   y и  z изначально не инициализированы, с чего вы взяли, что их значения не меняются?..

Comment: Почему в вопросе не приведены эти "разные значения", которые вы вводили?

Answer (score 4):

Второе слагаемое по порядку намного больше первого (при небольших значениях j), поэтому влияние первого слагаемого при точности вывода по умолчанию просто теряется.

Теряется оно при выводе небольшого количества значащих цифр, истинные значения отличаются. Однако при большей разнице в порядках и истинные значения сумм будут одинаковы (`1e100 + 1.0 = 1e100`) - из-за ограниченной точности вещественных чисел.

Вот так можно заметить различия:

```
 cout << std::cout.precision(15)<<"y = " << y << "\n";
 cout << std::cout.precision(15)<< "z = " << z << "\n";
```

Comment: Дополню комментарием. Второе слагаемое это `exp(10 * m) = exp(30) = 1.0686475e+13`